# How to make record to be table title

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table and its data

```
----------------------------
| ID | NAME | TYPE | VALUE |
----------------------------
| 1  |  A   | YES  | 10000 |
| 2  |  B   |  NO  |   100 |
| 3  |  A   |  NO  |   300 |
----------------------------
```

I wonder how to get data in sql like this :

```
-----------------------------
| ID | NAME | YES   |   NO  |
-----------------------------
| 1  |  A   | 10000 |   300 |
| 2  |  B   | NULL  |   100 |
-----------------------------
```

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pivot the data to do that.

```
select MIN(ID) as ID, NAME , 
       Max(Case when TYPE = 'Yes' then VALUE END) as `Yes`
       Max(Case when TYPE = 'No' then VALUE END) as `No`
From Yourtable
Group by NAME
```

**Note:** This assumes there are only two possible values(`Yes&No`) present in `TYPE` column.

Comment: you actually need to aggregate and take the MIN(ID) for this to be correct, leaving ID in will not aggregate the other values

Comment: @Matt - yeah, missed that.. Updated